# What is the time complexity in big-O notation of Algorithm X?

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, time-complexity

*[Knuth's Algorithm X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth's_Algorithm_X) is a recursive, nondeterministic, depth-first, backtracking algorithm* that solves the NP-complete problem exact cover (EC). (It actually finds all solutions to EC.)

I do not understand how such algorithm could do that. What is the time complexity of this algorithm in terms of big-O notation?

Here is the algorithm from Wikipedia.

> 1. If the matrix $A$ has no columns, the current partial solution is a valid solution; terminate successfully.
> 2. Otherwise choose a column $c$ (deterministically).
> 3. Choose a row $r$ such that $A_{r,c} = 1$ (nondeterministically).
> 4. Include row $r$ in the partial solution.
> 5. For each column $j$ such that $A_{r,j} = 1$,
>
>    - for each row $i$ such that $A_{i,j} = 1$,
>
>      - delete row $i$ from matrix $A$.
>    - delete column $j$ from matrix $A$.
> 6. Repeat this algorithm recursively on the reduced matrix A.

Step 3 of the algorithm is done nondeterministically. What does this mean? (I think this is the point why I cannot find the big-O complexity of the algorithm.)

An implementation of Algorithm X in python can be found in [Algorithm X in 30 lines!](http://www.cs.mcgill.ca/~aassaf9/python/algorithm_x.html) where I cannot find the nondeterministic choice of step 3.

Comment: For detailed analysis of complexity see: https://11011110.github.io/blog/2008/01/10/analyzing-algorithm-x.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its worst-case running time is exponential.

By "nondeterministic", this essentially means "try all possibilities".